# can i know what is the ui element use in the joox application?

Tags: ios, user-interface

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEZJ1.jpg)

Can anyone tell me that what is the ui element use at the right top of the application? The user is able to swipe left and right to swipe between the view controller and the green bar at the bottom of the icon will animate.

Comment: It would help if you trimmed the image down to the relevant part and maybe circle the exact UI element you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not only one element. In my app,I used three buttons and one cursor view to do this.